# PHPMailer no longer processing multipart email correctly

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've been using a PHPMailer script for years sending emails to my group. Everything was working great up until last week. Now when I send an email the multi-part is fully displayed as plain text.  Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '/fullpath/public_html/tmp/PHPmailer.php';
require '/fullpath/public_html/tmp/SMTP.php';
require '/fullpath/public_html/tmp/Exception.php';

$body  = $_POST['msgText'];

$mail  = new PHPMailer();

$mail->setFrom('MY WEB SITE EMAIL', 'ME');
$mail->addReplyTo('MY EMAIL', 'ME');
$mail->addAddress('MY EMAIL', 'ME');
$mail->Subject = $_POST['subjectText'];
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$a = $_POST['toText'];
// For output display
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en><head><title>My Test PHP Mailer</title></head>\n<body>\n<h1>My Test PHP Mailer</h1>\n<h4>Sending Emails to:</h4>\n<ul>";
foreach ($mail->parseAddresses($a) as $address) {
    $mail->addBCC($address['address'], $address['name']); // for release
//    $mail->addAddress($address['address'], $address['name']); // for testing
    echo "<li>Name: " . $address['name'] . " - address: [" . $address['address'] . "]</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  echo "<br>" . $_POST['toText'];
} else {
 echo "<form><textarea name=ta>" . $body . "'></textarea></form>";
}
echo "<p><a href='index.php'>Back to index.php</a></p>\n</body>\n</html>";
?>
```

And my email is showing up like this:

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--b1_5S1Pr6ILOHSPuOiGgJGQzPfIPsBjnsOmX6MAuoro
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Good luck to all, and thanks for participating,

--b1_5S1Pr6ILOHSPuOiGgJGQzPfIPsBjnsOmX6MAuoro
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

<HTML><HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></HEAD>
<BODY bgColor="#ffffff">
<div style="max-width:800px;border:1px solid #666666; padding:9px; background-color:white;">
<DIV><FONT face="Arial" color="#000080" size="6"><B><I>NFL
<FONT color="#C80000">Challenge</FONT> 2022</I></B></FONT></DIV>
<DIV><FONT face="Arial, Helvetica" color="#ff0000" size="4"><B>Hey Sportsfans,</B></FONT></DIV>
<br>
<DIV><FONT face="Arial" size="2">Good luck to all, and thanks for participating,</FONT></DIV>
<br>
</DIV></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>


--b1_5S1Pr6ILOHSPuOiGgJGQzPfIPsBjnsOmX6MAuoro--
```

I haven't made any changes in the last week. Why would the emails be sent as simply text and not do the multi-part encoding? This output is the same for all mail clients.

I have searched the internet for the last week and can't find anything that helps. I did update to the latest version of PHPMailer to see if that would fix the problem, but it still remains. I want the email to be sent as HTML and not have the raw details going out to all my friends.

Any suggestions, opinions or dumb looks appreciated.

==============[ UPDATE ]=================

I was asked to specify more details on my problem. When I tried initially, Stackoverflow gave me an error that this was a spam submission. So I'm going to try again and redact some details to hopefully avoid that error.

First - the email is being sent using PHPMailer 6.1.1
Second - the email clients receiving the emails that I have been able to test are: Gmail, Outlook, and Yahoo Mail.
Third - I was asked to share the raw source of the email (this is where I hope I can avoid the 'spam' error).

This is the last working email I sent, as reported from Gmail "show original":

```
Subject: NFL Challenge 2022 - Week 18 Reminder
X-PHP-Script: xxxxxxxxxxxx/file.php for 162.252.247.224
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1002:PHPmailer.php
Date: Fri, 6 Jan 2023 01:02:03 +0000
From: NFL Challenge <me@myserver>
Message-ID: <GdssaiyhOGwE5lgWdOnRMleJbhKIfeZQPc4TpJB74@www.starbase47.com>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.1.1 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="b1_GdssaiyhOGwE5lgWdOnRMleJbhKIfeZQPc4TpJB74"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4xfNLwjf/lI+ECbHq2uNTaPo2pDBlT0LgWHZfm+1mtCGh1qLdFoViGjgSHemmT9C8buRCOrt1A4pAvnGulYNkPiO6cJBSDRVv2s9yqB3tUM/GOH02Idbpt 4uA8x2WkhDDGrE1gBk+cE3ZeAWqXwfQWDQznYq5N7InVD9s4UlutNmMlACjSidhnEIrzVJHFZsR3gvGOSiEZDf8Xg4jjk51comuqnF4hLvF9slMWKexfPYfp 6Xxsb7BqWoHfbmSTB0WrMR6wzG3e0ybFGe3HDiMIPPCsHfCHUzaLjXMSfUCI8xcbnScfTz9t/00yLtSwLj4nu+sganzgBI433vpvFj28Aw7bDlm4K0iERspz shEaDRpZwHKD44xwCTSsa/zjvrXAdsOo39EuWLtn25QSOT3QYuEKmpe4M1mMGS6BH/oP3rxUGu89rDzc7fBcav7MtnNLI7Wz2kWAnBvuyrZWhKM/vBzLUUd/ uWtz/nhTNzzItSy1rm8ObR+cm6RuWil0uilXF9nF/gg5TzFOixzNgTuvexbclXCl198ACnro7gQfxMM47NeRuZkhQUjjOuhm+k0TeJyRKWD7S1ujA3qfndH/ 8LI=

--b1_GdssaiyhOGwE5lgWdOnRMleJbhKIfeZQPc4TpJB74
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

NFL
Challenge 2022
Hey Sportsfans, ...
```

This is the source of the email that didn't format correctly, again from Gmail "show source".

```
Subject: NFL Challenge 2022 - Playoffs Test
X-PHP-Script: www.starbase47.com/mytest_mail.php for 162.252.247.224 X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1002:PHPmailer.php
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2023 21:33:09 +0000 From: NFL Challenge <me@myserver> Message-ID: <5S1Pr6ILOHSPuOiGgJGQzPfIPsBjnsOmX6MAuoro@www.starbase47.com> X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.1.1 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary="b1_5S1Pr6ILOHSPuOiGgJGQzPfIPsBjnsOmX6MAuoro" Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Message-Id: <E1pG5C9-0006pY-1D@192.222.167.72.host.secureserver.net>
From: me@myserver
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4xfI/De/t+kmwbb6eY2xWVi89UxsAiJ5qMwBEnzqpJBSwnrpHKLYrLpRjMnFUNxqZVwAckeapMXSEzXsK71DSiMO5WP0VZxM0iNr0qMiD/lOxS2Sp5+Vb0 4nUe/KgwmKZcA8v6BUI5N0fFqt5Ha2nrzlg4ouBiPrZTTYgrTQ+UQoHWyWWl/LWrhDX5AUYdRYL/DI0Q7u5H+LjjhdKhAOdTeKAPsa+EEkVMxWbX/z27TF2m jzATQVQbCe7u4en0+gEgDg==

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--b1_5S1Pr6ILOHSPuOiGgJGQzPfIPsBjnsOmX6MAuoro
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

NFL
Challenge 2022
Hey Sportsfans, ...
```

If you need me to share more details (like from another client, or the raw PHPMailer code that I have on my server) please let me know.

Thank you in advance - Einstein47

Comment: Can you look at the actual source of the email? And then check where the first `Content-Type` starts, and what it looks like? There should, at least, be one that defines the `boundary`.

Comment: The Headers are generated by the PHPMailer code. The `Content-Type` does define the `boundary` as a random string, and that `boundary` is used consistently in the body of the email.

Comment: I am reviewing the source of the last email that worked and the first that failed. The biggest change is the difference in CRLF in the headers. But I can't control those with PHPMailer. What would cause the CRLF to be missing?

Comment: Are you **sure** all the email headers are on a single line? Because that's what you're saying. Have you checked this in a proper code editor? If you want our help it is important to be very clear. Don't say: _"This output is the same for all mail clients."_, but specify which clients you've actually tested. Don't say: _"The biggest change is the difference in CRLF in the headers"_, but specify, unambiguously, what that difference **exactly** is. Edit your question, don't use a comment, if you have something to say that clarifies your question.

Comment: I can tell you're not using the latest version of PHPMailer because the MIME preamble was dropped in recent versions, and it's still present in your output. We can't tell anything without seeing the full message structure. You may be running into an issue with the mail function which sometimes forcibly wraps lines before it's necessary, breaking the message formatting. An easy workaround for that is to switch to using SMTP to localhost, which is also both safer and faster (just call `$mail->isSMTP()`).

Comment: I'm not saying it's a DNS problem, but it's a DNS problem. host.secureserver.net isn't starbase47.com.

Comment: It does indeed seems like you're using another mailserver, and that this new mailserver chops up your headers. The `boundary` is no longer part of the `Content-Type:` header, and therefore your email clients cannot use the boundary to separate the various parts of the email.